# Insert empty lines without entering insert mode

Tags: vim

I often find myself bouncing on o or O and ctrl{ to insert blank lines and get back out of insert mode.

Thinking there must be a simpler way, and hoping to retain my cursor position, I hacked together these sloppy macros:

```
map <Leader>O :let cursorpos = getpos(".")<CR>:i<CR><CR>.<CR>:let cursorpos[1] = cursorpos[1] + 1<CR>:call setpos('.', cursorpos)<CR>
map <Leader>o :let cursorpos = getpos(".")<CR>:a<CR><CR>.<CR>:call setpos('.', cursorpos)<CR>
```

However, this doesn't allow for ranges. It would be nice to be able to go 5\O and get 5 blanks above my current line.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this to allow ranges and still return to the original cursor position when done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `:call append(linenumber, repeat([''], 5))`. It won't move the cursor.

Comment: Excellent, that's perfect. I figured there had to be some more elegant way.

Switched it up to:

    map <Leader>O :<C-U>call append(line(".") -1, repeat([''], v:count1))<CR>
    map <Leader>o :<C-U>call append(line("."), repeat([''], v:count1))<CR>

to respond to ranges. Thanks!

Comment: But in this example if we apply a "counting version" it will move the cursor up/down as well.

Comment: @user3663882. We need to replace `:call`  with `:<c-u>call` and replace 5 with `v:count1` for instance. Or keep the 5 and start the command with `<C-\><C-N>` or `<esc>` to clear the count.

Answer (score 10):

The [unimpaired](http://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin adds mappings that do what you want. You can [insert a blank line above the cursor](http://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/a59a121ee6fd7337a5b3a115aba32de6fbf5f0b2/doc/unimpaired.txt#L43-49) with `[<space>`, or below the cursor with `]<space>`. Both of these mappings can be prepended with a count.

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my .vimrc

```
"create new line below current line without leaving normal mode or moving cursor
noremap - m`o<Esc>``
"create new line above current line without leaving normal mode or moving cursor
noremap _ m`O<Esc>``
```

I prefer this solution for several reasons:

- I don't normally use the <kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>_</kbd> keys in normal mode and they are located on the same physical key on my keyboard.
- It just seems like installing a plugin for this is overkill. I avoid downloading plugins for simple things since they introduce new code to my environment that I don't yet fully understand or trust and it may interfere with other customizations or plugins.
- I tried the solution from the author of this question located in his comment under the accepted answer, but after using this, the <kbd>.</kbd> command does strange and disturbing things.
- I usually prefer pressing <kbd>.</kbd> multiple times over passing a numeric argument, so that instead of sitting there counting things on my fingers, I just keep pressing <kbd>.</kbd> until it looks right (less conceptual visualization and more real vision). Unfortunately even this solution does not work the way I want with the <kbd>.</kbd> command. However, by mapping <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>_</kbd>, these can be pressed repeatedly for the same effect. Just a shame it is not closer to the home row...

***WARNING:*** Marking the <kbd>`</kbd> key affects the jump list. You can use any other mark if that makes your pleasure++